# DateTimeZone to/from database

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm trying to get a handle on using the [Noda Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) framework by Jon Skeet (and others).

How do I store the **DateTimeZone** and retrieve it from the database.  I thought the **Id** property value might be the one to set to the database, but how do I create a DateTimeZone from the Id since DateTimeZone is an abstract class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storing the ID is fine, and you'd get it back using the relevant [`IDateTimeZoneProvider`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.0.x/docs/api/html/T_NodaTime_IDateTimeZoneProvider.htm) and its [indexer](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.0.x/docs/api/html/P_NodaTime_IDateTimeZoneProvider_Item.htm), normally retrieved via [`DateTimeZoneProviders`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.0.x/docs/api/html/T_NodaTime_DateTimeZoneProviders.htm). For example:

```
var london = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
```

You do need to know which provider you used, of course - IDs are only scoped to the provider, effectively.